# Laravel Console Test with unpredictable output

Tags: laravel, testing, console, tdd, laravel-artisan

Is it possible to test Laravel Artisan Command with unpredictable output?

For example, my artisan command has an output:

`Your new password is: bGiJjIjAT0`

That `bGiJjIjAT0` is actually a random string. The artisan command generate that random string.

AFAIK, Console test `expectsOutput` expects exact strings.

Comment: How can you test a random string? It is inherently in the question itself "random string", so your test can never "guess" what string it will be... what you can do is test the underlying code creating the random string

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Artisan::call('your:command');
    $output = Artisan::output();
    $this->assertStringContainsString('Your new password is: ', $output);
```